# Existential antipattern, how to avoid

Tags: haskell

The below seems to work... but it seems clumsy.

```
data Point = Point Int Int
data Box = Box Int Int
data Path = Path [Point]
data Text = Text

data Color = Color Int Int Int
    data WinPaintContext = WinPaintContext Graphics.Win32.HDC

class CanvasClass vc paint where
    drawLine :: vc -> paint -> Point -> Point -> IO ()
    drawRect :: vc -> paint -> Box -> IO ()
    drawPath :: vc -> paint -> Path -> IO ()

class (CanvasClass vc paint) => TextBasicClass vc paint where
    basicDrawText :: vc -> paint -> Point -> String -> IO ()

instance CanvasClass WinPaintContext WinPaint where
    drawLine = undefined
    drawRect = undefined
    drawPath = undefined

instance TextBasicClass WinPaintContext WinPaint where
    basicDrawText (WinPaintContext a) = winBasicDrawText a

op :: CanvasClass vc paint => vc -> Box -> IO ()
op canvas _ = do
    basicDrawText canvas WinPaint (Point 30 30) "Hi"

open :: IO ()
open = do
    makeWindow (Box 300 300) op

winBasicDrawText :: Graphics.Win32.HDC -> WinPaint -> Point -> String -> IO ()
winBasicDrawText hdc _ (Point x y) str = do
    Graphics.Win32.setBkMode hdc Graphics.Win32.tRANSPARENT
    Graphics.Win32.setTextColor hdc (Graphics.Win32.rgb 255 255 0)
    Graphics.Win32.textOut hdc 20 20 str
    return ()

windowsOnPaint :: (WinPaintContext -> Box -> IO ()) ->
                  Graphics.Win32.RECT ->
                  Graphics.Win32.HDC ->
                  IO ()
windowsOnPaint f rect hdc = f (WinPaintContext hdc) (Box 30 30)

makeWindow :: Box -> (WinPaintContext -> Box -> IO ()) -> IO ()
makeWindow (Box w h) onPaint =
  Graphics.Win32.allocaPAINTSTRUCT $ \ lpps -> do
  hwnd <- createWindow w h (wndProc lpps (windowsOnPaint onPaint))
  messagePump hwnd
```

Now, what seems to be the preferred way is to just simply have

```
data Canvas = Canvas {
    drawLine :: Point -> Point -> IO (),
    drawRect :: Box -> IO (),
    drawPath :: Path -> IO ()
}

hdc2Canvas :: Graphics.Win32.HDC -> Paint -> IO ( Canvas )
hdc2Canvas hdc paint = Canvas { drawLine = winDrawLine hdc paint ... }
```

HOWEVER...

We like to keep paints around and mutate them throughout the drawing process, as they're expensive to create and destroy. A paint could just be a list like [bgColor red, fgColor blue, font "Tahoma"] or something, or it could be a pointer to an internal structure the paint system uses (this is an abstraction over windows GDI, but will ultimately abstract over direct2d and coregraphics), which have "paint" objects which I don't wanna recreate over and over and then bind over.

The beauty of existentials in my mind is that they can opaquely wrap something to abstract over it, and we can save it somewhere, pull it back, whatever. When you partially apply, I think there is the problem that the thing you've partially applied is now "stuck inside" the container. Here's an example. Say I have a paint object like

```
data Paint = Paint {
    setFg :: Color -> IO () ,
    setBg :: Color -> IO ()
}
```

Where can I place the pointer? When I give the Paint to some function in Canvas, how does he get the pointer? What's the right way to design this API?

Comment: What is `WinPaint`? Do you have a main that runs and does something, so we can see what this is all supposed to do? Where is the existentially quantified type that you are looking to eliminate?

Comment: WinPaint is just something that wraps a pointer to some kind of platform specific drawing context which holds the foreground, background, font, etc. I didn't explicitly existentially quantify them, but I'd existentially quantify CanvasClass to Canvas. "Open" here is main, and is supposed to just open a window with a bit of text in it. This code doesn't work but I hope it gets my intention across.

Comment: "What's the right way to design this API?" seems more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com. You're going to get quite varied responses to that question. Mine, for example, would start with "Get rid of IO()" or "Look at how gloss does it", neither of which has anything to do with existential quantification.

Comment: "Where can I place the pointer? When I give the Paint to some function in Canvas, how does he get the pointer?" ...uh, what pointer, exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The Interface**

First, you need to ask "What are my requirements?". Let's state in plain English what we want a canvas to do (these are my guesses based on your question):

- Some canvases can have shapes put on them
- Some canvases can have text put on them
- Some canvases change what they do based on a paint
- We don't know what paints are yet, but they will be different for different canvases

Now we translate these ideas into Haskell. Haskell is a "types-first" language, so when we are talking about requirements and design, we are probably talking about types.

- In Haskell, when we see the word "some" while talking about types, we think of type classes. For example, the `show` class says "some types can be represented as strings".
- When we talk about something we don't know about yet, while talking about requirements, that's a type where we don't know what it is yet. That's a type variable.
- "put on them" seems to mean that we'd take have a canvas, put something on it, and have a canvas again.

Now we could write classes for each of these requirements:

```
class ShapeCanvas c where -- c is the type of the Canvas
    draw :: Shape -> c -> c

class TextCanvas c where
    write :: Text -> c -> c

class PaintCanvas p c where -- p is the type of Paint
    load :: p -> c -> c
```

The type variable `c` is only used once, appearing as `c -> c`. This suggests we could make these more general by replacing `c -> c` with `c`.

```
class ShapeCanvas c where -- c is the type of the canvas
    draw :: Shape -> c

class TextCanvas c where
    write :: Text -> c

class PaintCanvas p c where -- p is the type of paint
    load :: p -> c
```

Now `PaintCanvas` looks like a `class` that is problematic in Haskell. It's hard for the type system to figure out what's going on in classes like

```
class Implicitly a b where
    convert :: b -> a
```

I'd alleviate this by changing `PaintCanvas` to take advantage of the `TypeFamilies` extension.

```
class PaintCanvas c where 
    type Paint c :: * -- (Paint c) is the type of Paint for canvases of type c
    load :: (Paint c) -> c
```

Now, let's put together everything for our interface, including your data types for shapes and text (modified to make sense to me):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Data.Canvas (
    Point(..),
    Shape(..),
    Text(..),
    ShapeCanvas(..),
    TextCanvas(..),
    PaintCanvas(..)
) where

data Point = Point Int Int

data Shape = Dot Point
           | Box Point Point 
           | Path [Point]

data Text = Text Point String

class ShapeCanvas c where -- c is the type of the Canvas
    draw :: Shape -> c

class TextCanvas c where
    write :: Text -> c

class PaintCanvas c where 
    type Paint c :: * -- (Paint c) is the type of Paint for canvases of type c
    load :: (Paint c) -> c
```

**Some Examples**

This section will introduce an additional requirement for useful canvases besides those we have already worked out. It is the analog of what we lost when we replaced `c -> c` with `c` in the canvas classes.

Let's start with your first example code, `op`. With our new interface it's simply:

```
op :: (TextCanvas c) => c
op = write $ Text (Point 30 30) "Hi"
```

Let's make a slightly more complicated example. How about something that draws an "X"? We can make the first stroke of the "X"

```
ex :: (ShapeCanvas c) => c
ex = draw $ Path [Point 10 10, Point 20 20]
```

But we have no way to add another `Path` for the cross stroke. We need some way to put two drawing steps together. Something with type `c -> c -> c` would be perfect. The simplest Haskell class I can think of that provides this is `Monoid a`'s `mappend :: a -> a -> a`. A `Monoid` requires an identity and associativity. Is it resonable to assume that there's a drawing operation on canvases that leaves them untouched? That sounds quite reasonable. Is it reasonable to assume that three drawing operations, done in the same order, do the same thing even if the first two are performed together, and then the third, or if the first is performed, and then the second and third are performed together? Again, that seems quite reasonable to me. This suggest we can write `ex` as:

```
ex :: (Monoid c, ShapeCanvas c) => c
ex = (draw $ Path [Point 10 10, Point 20 20]) `mappend` (draw $ Path [Point 10 20, Point 20 10])
```

Finally, let's consider something interactive, that decides what to draw based on something external:

```
randomDrawing :: (MonadIO m, ShapeCanvas (m ()), TextCanvas (m ())) => m ()
randomDrawing = do
    index <- liftIO . getStdRandom $ randomR (0,2)
    choices !! index        
    where choices = [op, ex, return ()]
```

This doesn't quite work, because we don't have an instance for `(Monad m) => Monoid (m ())` so that `ex` will work. We could use `Data.Semigroup.Monad` from the reducers package, or add one ourselves, but that puts us in incoherent instances land. It'd be easier to change ex to:

```
ex :: (Monad m, ShapeCanvas (m ())) => m ()
ex = do
    draw $ Path [Point 10 10, Point 20 20]
    draw $ Path [Point 10 20, Point 20 10]
```

But the type system can't quite figure out that the unit from the first `draw` is the same as the unit from the second. Our difficulty here suggests additional requirements, that we couldn't quite put our finger on at first:

- Canvases extend existing sequences of operations, providing operations for drawing, writing text, etc.

Stealing directly from http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/06/from-zero-to-cooperative-threads-in-33.html:

- When you hear "sequence of instructions" you should think: "monad".
- When you qualify that with "extend" you should think: "monad transformer".

Now we realize our canvas implementation is most likely going to be a monad transformer. We can go back to our interface, and change it so that each of the classes is a class for a monad, similar to transformers' `MonadIO` class and mtl's monad classes.

**The Interface, revisited**

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Data.Canvas (
    Point(..),
    Shape(..),
    Text(..),
    ShapeCanvas(..),
    TextCanvas(..),
    PaintCanvas(..)
) where

data Point = Point Int Int

data Shape = Dot Point
           | Box Point Point 
           | Path [Point]

data Text = Text Point String

class Monad m => ShapeCanvas m where -- c is the type of the Canvas
    draw :: Shape -> m ()

class Monad m => TextCanvas m where
    write :: Text -> m ()

class Monad m => PaintCanvas m where 
    type Paint m :: * -- (Paint c) is the type of Paint for canvases of type c
    load :: (Paint m) -> m ()
```

**Examples, revisited**

Now all of our example drawing operations are actions in some unknown `Monad` m:

```
op :: (TextCanvas m) => m ()
op = write $ Text (Point 30 30) "Hi"

ex :: (ShapeCanvas m) => m ()
ex = do
    draw $ Path [Point 10 10, Point 20 20]
    draw $ Path [Point 10 20, Point 20 10]


randomDrawing :: (MonadIO m, ShapeCanvas m, TextCanvas m) => m ()
randomDrawing = do
    index <- liftIO . getStdRandom $ randomR (0,2)
    choices !! index        
    where choices = [op, ex, return ()]
```

We can also make an example using paint. Since we don't know what paints will exist, they all have to be provided externally (as arguments to the example):

```
checkerBoard :: (ShapeCanvas m, PaintCanvas m) => Paint m -> Paint m -> m ()
checkerBoard red black = 
    do
        load red
        draw $ Box (Point 10 10) (Point 20 20)
        draw $ Box (Point 20 20) (Point 30 30)
        load black
        draw $ Box (Point 10 20) (Point 20 30)
        draw $ Box (Point 20 10) (Point 30 20)
```

**An Implementation**

*If you can make your code work to draw points, boxes, lines and text using various paints without introducing abstraction, we can change it to implement the interface from the first section.*

Comment: I've read comments before about avoiding type classes unless they are necessary, and that type classes are usually "only" useful when the structure you deal with is also supposed to behave according to laws. What's your take on this, seeing as you use type classes quite (from what I can tell) liberally? I'm just a newbie myself and if I'm way out of line with this (potentially very stupid) question just tell me so. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to structure code with Haskell, coming from an OOP world!

Comment: If you want to see something similar done without type classes, take a look at gloss. The "liberal" use of type classes here comes from the inferred requirement that not all canvases support the same things, but they should look the same to a programmer. A question like this one solicits answers that may look nothing like each other, nor like what the original question posed. I try to answer them as close to the original question as possible, thus there are type classes for the same things the original question had type classes for.

Comment: This is absolutely incredible. Thank you so much for your time and the detail and wonderful pacing!