# How can I prove to GHC that (b ~ Foo)?

Tags: haskell

## New Question

I'm not going to pretend that I know how to think or talk about haskell. In pseudo-java-oo-jargon:

What I want to do is have a "structure" that "implements" an "interface."  Part of that interface is a function which returns an object which implements another interface.

```
interface IFiz {}

interface IBuz {
    function IFiz getFiz() 
}

class Foo implements IFiz { ... }
class Bar implements IBuz {
    IFiz fiz = new Foo();
    function getFiz() {
        return fiz;
    }
}
```

How can I do this in Haskell?  My attempt at doing this is described below.

---

## Old Question

How can I prove to GHC that (b ~ Foo)?

My understanding of the problem:

Foo is an instance of the type class Fiz.

I would like Bar to be an instance of the type class Buz.

However, the compiler is unable to deduce that (b ~ Foo) in the implementation of the `punk` method.  But what else could it be?  I attempted to add data constraints using the deprecated direct way, as well as using GADTs, but neither seemed to work (I continued to get the exact same error.)

```
data Foo = Foo Int                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
data Bar = Bar Foo                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
class Fiz a where                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    funk :: a -> a -- Not important, I just wanted to put something in Fiz                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
class Buz a where                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    punk :: Fiz b => a -> b                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
instance Fiz Foo where                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    funk a = a                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
instance Buz Bar where                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   punk (Bar foo) = foo
```

---

```
Could not deduce (b ~ Foo)
from the context (Fiz b)
  bound by the type signature for punk :: Fiz b => Bar -> b
  at Test.hs:42:5-8
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for punk :: Fiz b => Bar -> b at Test.hs:42:5
Relevant bindings include punk :: Bar -> b (bound at Test.hs:42:5)
In the expression: foo
In an equation for ‘punk’: punk (Bar foo) = foo
```

Answer (score 6):

This type signature:

```
class Buz a where
  punk :: Fiz b => a -> b
```

says that `punk` must be able to return something of type `b` for any type `b` given it is instance of `Fiz`. So the problem is not that compiler cannot deduce that `Foo` is instance of `Fiz`, but that the return value is not `Quux`, which is an instance of `Fiz`.

```
data Quux = Quux 

instance Fiz Quux where
  funk a = a
```

If you want to have type class with function returning any instance of `Fiz`, you can use ExistentionalQuantification extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ExistentialQuantification #-}   
data Foo = Foo Int
data Bar = Bar Foo
data SomeFiz = forall a . Fiz a => SomeFiz a
class Fiz a where
  funk :: a -> a

class Buz a where
  punk :: a -> SomeFiz

instance Fiz Foo where
  funk a = a

instance Buz Bar where
  punk (Bar foo) = SomeFiz foo
```

Otherwise if you really mean to implement this typeclass, you can only do this by passing bottoms to `funk`:

```
instance Buz Bar where
  punk _ = funk undefined
-- or for example:
instance Buz Bar where
  punk _ = funk (funk undefined)
```

or by fixing funk:

```
instance Buz Bar where
  punk _ = fix funk
```

If you could give more details on what you want to achieve, maybe I'll be able to give more helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated my question with an OO version of what I want to accomplish.  The motivating example is a MetricSpace typeclass which defines a function which (is supposed) to return the underlying space (an instance of the Space typeclass.)  The question I posted was the best minimal example of the problem I could think up.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

The class `Buz` says that if `a` has an instance for `Buz`, then for **every** `b` that has a `Fiz` instance, you can provide a function from `a -> b`. The class `Fiz` provides virtually no help in producing a `b`; `funk` will only give you a `b` if you already have a `b`.

You are probably misunderstanding the error message from GHC. Type inference goes both ways. In this case, `b` comes from the signature for `punk` in the class `Buz`. It *requires* that the result of `punk` be something of type `b` for every type `b`. `Foo` is not something of every type.

```
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for punk :: Fiz b => Bar -> b at Test.hs:42:5
```

Comment: I still don't get it.  `punk` is defined in `Buz` to return *some* instance of `Fiz`.  `foo` is of type `Foo` which is an instance `Fiz`.  You cannot construct a `Bar` such that given `(Bar something)`, `something` is not a `Foo`...  I get that there can be other instances of `Buz` out there, but this `punk` is being defined for `Bar` only...

Comment: `punk` is define in `Buz` to return a value for *every* type that is an instance of `Fiz`.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that I am beginning to see where my mental model of haskell starts to deviate from reality.  I have updated my question, can you please take another look?

Comment: @RealJohnConnor Your **new** question should probably be a **new** separate question. It's ok to learn things from one question, be done with it, and ask another question; it's more valuable for other people who might encounter the same problems if each problem is a separate question.

Comment: @RealJohnConnor I would not be surprised if a follow up question has been asked and answered multiple times. A quick search knowing that people coming from OO generally stray into existential types finds [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061828/existential-antipattern-how-to-avoid) and [this article](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/). If reading those doesn't provide the insight you need, ask a new question specifically about the problem you have with metric spaces.